# Custom event and onMouseEnter in one div

Tags: elm

I'm trying to attach two events to one div, but am having some difficulty. The code compiles when one of those events is attached, but not two. I'll explain what is now working, and then how it breaks when I try to attach another event. The reason it is breaking is very intuitive, but I wouldn't know how to fix the problem.

Right now I have:

```
dragHereOverlay : { item : String, color : String } -> Html Msg
dragHereOverlay item =
    App.map (\d -> GetPositionDragHere d item) <|
        div
            [ on "mouseenter" decodeRectangle
            , attribute "class" "drag-here"
            , sharedStyles
            ]
            []

decodeRectangle : Decode.Decoder Rectangle
decodeRectangle =
    let
        rectangle =
            DOM.target
                :> DOM.boundingClientRect
    in
        rectangle
```

So, on a "mouseenter" event, decodeRectangle is called, which returns a Decoder structure with the dimensions of the div. 'On "mouseenter"', returns a Rectangle structure. This is then mapped, returning a GetPositionDragHere Msg.

What I'd like to do is this:

```
dragHereOverlay : { item : String, color : String } -> Html Msg
dragHereOverlay item =
    App.map (\d -> GetPositionDragHere d item) <|
        div
            [ on "mouseenter" decodeRectangle
            , onMouseLeave DoSomethingElse
            , attribute "class" "drag-here"
            , sharedStyles
            ]
            []
```

Ie, on a "mouseenter" event, fire a GetPositiondragHere Msg with the Rectangle dimensions of the div (returned by decodeRectangle), and on a "mouseleave" event do something else.

This is the error :

> The 1st and 2nd elements are different types of values.
>
> ```
> 225|             [ on "mouseenter" decodeRectangle
> 226|>            , onMouseLeave RestoreList
> 227|             , attribute "class" "drag-here"
> 228|             , sharedStyles
> 229|             ]
> ```
>
> The 1st element has this type:
>
> ```
> Attribute { height : Float, left : Float, top : Float, width : Float }
> ```
>
> But the 2nd is:
>
> ```
> Attribute Msg
> ```
>
> Hint: All elements should be the same type of value so that we can
>   iterate through the list without running into unexpected values.
>
> Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the compile error

Comment: Done! Now I have to write more stuff to be allowed to post this :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the error message tells you the problem. You need to change

```
on "mouseenter" decodeRectangle
```

to

```
on "mouseenter" (Json.Decode.map tagger decodeRectangle)
```

where tagger needs to be defined and have this type signature

```
tagger: Rectangle -> Msg
```